# Hyper-V Web Server in Windows Server 2012 Not Accessible Externally

Tags: iis, webserver, hyper-v, windows-server-2012

I have a Windows Server 2012 running Hyper-V which has a virtual server running Windows Server 2012. Both the physical and virtual server are connected to a domain (hosted on a separate server) and both are assigned static IPs. The virtual server is running IIS and the website is running and accessible within the network. However, I cannot see the website outside of the network. I've opened the port on the router and pointed the port to the virtual servers IP address. Any suggestions you can offer would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong port. Because I have another web server running using up port 443 I had arbitrarily chose to use port 445 for the new web server and I found out that that is a reserved port. So I switched to port 8080 and opened up the port on the windows firewall and now it's working perfectly!